# Ошибка при выполнении кода ассемблера в Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, ассемблер, delphi-7

Создал две функции на ассемблере: первое вычисляет разность, второе произведение. Вычисляет сумму и разность.

Код:

```
// 2. Функция умножения

function Umnojenie(x, y: integer): integer;
asm
mov ebx,y
  mov eax,x
  imul ebx
end;


// 4 Функция деления

function divider(x, y: integer): integer;
asm
  mov eax,x
  mov ebx,y
  div eax
end;    

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);       // процедура умножения
  var a,b,c: integer;   //ïåðåìåííàÿ ðåçóëüòàòà
begin

  a:= StrToInt(edit1.text);
  b:= StrToInt(edit2.text);

  c:= Umnojenie(a, b);

  label1.visible:= true;
  label1.caption:= IntToStr(c);

end; 

//аналогично с делением
```

Выдает ошибку:

[image: bags on delphi 7]

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: текст ошибки должен быть указан в виде текста, а не только в виде картинки

Answer (score 4):

1. Вы имеете право модифицировать только три регистра `EAX`, `ECX`, `EDX`. Если Вы модифицируете другие регистры, то при выходе из функции Вы должны восстановить их значения
2. В Делфи, по умолчанию, для функций принято соглашение `register`. Это значит, что три первых параметра передаются через регистры `EAX`, `EDX`, `ECX` (именно в таком порядке)

Таким образом, Ваши функции примут такой вид

```
// 2. Функция умножения

function Umnojenie(x, y: integer): integer;
asm
  imul edx  // eax = eax * edx
end;


// 4 Функция деления

function divider(x, y: integer): integer;
asm
  mov ecx, edx
  cdq
  idiv ecx  // eax = edx:eax / ecx
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так (проверку деления на нуль не делал):

```
Program HelloWorld(output);

{$asmmode intel}
function LongMul(X, Y: Longint): Longint; assembler;
asm
  mov eax,X
  imul Y
end;

function LongDiv(X, Y: Longint): Longint; assembler;
asm
  mov ecx,edx
  cdq
  idiv ecx
end;

begin
  writeln('mul: ',LongMul(2,4));
  writeln('div: ',LongDiv(16,3));
end.
```

[Тут онлайн выполнение](http://ideone.com/QzLtp1), правда FreePascal.

Comment: Умножение получилось, а деление с переменными типа longint не получается из-за той же ошибки

Comment: Дополнил, смотрите предыдущий ответ.

Comment: 1. Ассемблерная вставка может спокойно портить регистры? 2. Почему бы не использовать `__fastcall`, чтобы аргументы уже были в регистрах?

Comment: Во ФриПасквиле и Дельфи, ЕМНИП, существуют соглашения на push регистров и ret. Поэтому, если соблюдать - будет все пучком. А если спецом нарушать - конечно можно испортить. А загонять все аргументы в регистры не обязательно, многие операторы вполне берут операнд из памяти.